# RangeError: call stack exceed on async .eachSeries

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

At last, an actual stack overflow error reported on stackoverflow!

I get the following error in the code below:

```
var m = pathA.substr(-(pathB.length)); // var 
                                              ^
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

I'm fairly sure the answer is reported here, towards the bottom:

https://github.com/caolan/async/issues/75

However, I don't understand how to fix my code. I am not calling sync functions inside async functions, as far as I know. Can anyone clarify what I have to do to fix my code?

I'm iterating over the cross-product of a result-set to concatenate the path strings where one is the substring of the other.

```
var i = 0;
    async.eachSeries(results.rows, function (r, next2a) {
        var pathA = results.rows[i].id_path;
        var j = 0;
        async.eachSeries(results.rows, function (r2, next1a) {
            var pathB = results.rows[j].id_path;
            //check i=j
            if (!(i == j)) {
                var m = pathA.substr(-(pathB.length)); // var m = (pathA || '').substr(-((pathB) ? pathB.length : 0));
                if ((m == pathB) && (pathA.length > pathB.length)) {
                    logger.log('DEBUG', (pathB + ' => ' + pathA));
                    conn.query("UPDATE user_token_details SET id_l1=$1, id_l2=$2, id_l3=$3, id_l4=$4,id_l5=$5,id_path2=$9, id_path=$6 WHERE token_uuid=$7 AND user_uuid=$8",
                        [results.rows[i].id_l1, results.rows[i].id_l2, results.rows[i].id_l3, results.rows[i].id_l4, results.rows[i].id_l5, results.rows[i].id_path,
                            results.rows[j].token_uuid, user_uuid, results.rows[j].id_path],
                        function (error, result) {
                            if (error) {
                                throw error;
                            }
                            j++;
                            next1a();

                        })
                } else {
                    j++;
                    next1a();
                }
            } else {
                j++;
                next1a();
            }


        }, function () {
            i++;
            next2a();
        });


    }, function (err) {
});
```

Here is the form of this spaghetti:

```
var A = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4...300];
async.eachSeries(A, function (a, next_a) {

    async.eachSeries(A, function (b, next_b) {
       // "Range Error: Maximum call stack size exceeded"
        doSomethingAsync(a,b, function () {
        next_a();
        });

    }, function (err) {
        next_b();
    })

}, function (err) {
    // resume
})
```

Comment: woah, I consider myself pretty good with async, but no way in hell am I going to try to figure out THAT code. try to boil it down to something a bit more humanly parsable or I suspect you will get 0 answers here

Comment: It's related to this problem: https://github.com/rdegges/node-lupus   http://www.rdegges.com/for-loops-in-node/

Comment: @mkoryak I added a second example

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `async.eachSeries` only behaves asynchronously if the callback inside it is called asynchronously. In your case, your last two calls to `next1a` are not performing a query, so they occur synchronously, and thus extend the call stack. In this case, you are likely iterating enough that you hit max stack depth. The simplest fix is to always call `next1a` asynchronously.

Replace each instance of

```
next1a();
```

with

```
setImmediate(next1a);
```

except the one that is already async because of the query. Note that while `process.nextTick(next1a)` would also work, it has the potential to block the event loop from processing any other tasks. This is because `process.nextTick` queues the callback as a `microtask`, whereas `setImmediate` queues the callback as a `macrotask`.

Comment: Totally awesome thank you for solution and explanation.

Comment: I'm curious if that will fix it.  When I experimented with nextTick, I found it to work just like a synchronous function call (node v0.10.29)

Comment: It will. `nextTick` triggers a callback outside the current execution flow, so the stack will be unwound before it is executed.

Comment: @loganfsmyth after making those changes, I get: `(node) warning: Recursive process.nextTick detected. This will break in the next version of node. Please use setImmediate for recursive deferral.` This is printed out a few hundred times then crashes as before.

Comment: Fixed by using `process.nextTick(function() {next1a});` although not sure why.

Comment: Ahh right, my mistake. You should probably use `setImmediate(next1a)`. Your `"fix"` in fact just never calls the function so it will never iterate to the next item.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks. Yeah, my final async completion block was never getting called. :) `setImmediate` fixes that.